# SymmetricDS length for type varchar cannot exceed N

Tags: java, database, h2, symmetricds

so I'm trying to use [symmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org) for replicating java h2 database to postgres. I'm using the `zip` file simple configuration. Here is what happen. I followed the getting started guide, download the symmetricds, and try the demo, then I tried with my own configuration with some table in the trigger. But:

- If I replicate the table without `varchar` field in `h2` it works perfectly fine.
- If I have a table that has `varchar` field in it, it crash during creating the table.

`JdbcSqlTemplate - ERROR: length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760
  Position: 161.  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "asset"(
    "db_id" BIGINT NOT NULL  DEFAULT nextval('"asset_db_id_seq"'),
    "id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "account_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR(2147483647) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(2147483647),
    "quantity" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "decimals" SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    "initial_quantity" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "height" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "latest" BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'TRUE' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("db_id")
)`

indeed a clear error saying the varchar should not exceed 255, but that's how the source database is, is there anyway to force any varchar to `TEXT` type? or are there any other way around this? or is this a bug in `symmetricds` has yet to be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: there’s a clob column type that could be used with streaming, avoiding extraction of data from these 2GB columns. are you sure that you need as much space for a name and a description?

Comment: the problem is I need to as I can not to touch the h2 schema while solving this problem, the created table on postgres can be only varchar(255), is there way to do this?

Comment: if possible add a mirroring table to h2 with an insert/update/delete triggers on “asset” table to copy changes to the mirroring table with varchar up to 255 characters and configure sync from the mirroring table to the targeting db

Comment: hi @BorisPavlović thanks for the time, in the end I did the table creation manually to the target database using `dbexport` tools to generate the query and `dbimport` to generate the table. I still need to tweak the query result of `dbexport` thou, the `varchar(2147483647)` before executing `dbimport`. Thanks for the help thou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to go way around this by creating the table on target database manually. Here is what I did before running `bin/sym`.

- generate query for table I want to create using `dbexport` by `bin/dbexport --engine corp-000 --compatible=postgres --no-data table_a table_b > samples/create_asset_and_trade.sql`
- modify the flaw in generated query file `samples/create_asset_and_trade.sql`. in my case it's the length of the `varchar`.
- after fixing that, run the generated query to fill in the target database using `dbimport`. `bin/dbimport --engine store-001 samples/create_asset_and_trade.sql`.
- running `bin/sym` should be okay now, it'll detect that the table is already created, and skip the table creation step.

This is not the ideal way, but it should work for now.